# Sequelize TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: javascript, sequelize-cli

I am trying to update a sequelize model partially that contains a string array value separated by semicolons.

```
languages: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      get() {
        if (this.getDataValue('languages') === null) {
          return [];
        } else {
          return this.getDataValue('languages').split(';');
        }
      },
      set(val) {
        if (val.length === 0) {
          this.setDataValue('languages', null);
        } else {
          this.setDataValue('languages', val.join(';'));
        }
      },
    },
```

Comment: You really should not store delimited list of values in a field.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. Before updating the value it reads the current value and it gives as undefined when it is null in the database. By enhancing the if check it resolves the issue.

```
 languages: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  get() {
    if (this.getDataValue('languages') === null || this.getDataValue('languages') === undefined) {
      return [];
    } else {
      return this.getDataValue('languages').split(';');
    }
  },
  set(val) {
    if (val.length === 0) {
      this.setDataValue('languages', null);
    } else {
      this.setDataValue('languages', val.join(';'));
    }
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

It is better to check if the variable is `null` or `undefined`, remember that both values are different. `null` means nothing, null was assigned, whereas `undefined` means a variable was declared but no value was assigned to it.

You could do that

```
 if (!!this.getDataValue('languages')) {
      return this.getDataValue('languages').split(';');
    } else {
      return [];
    }
```

**Long answer**

If you want to intercept all your request and replace values, E.g: In case it is a nullable list, I want to display `[]`, In case it is a nullable boolean, I want to display `false`.

You may want to use a middleware to do that.

It would be something like below code:

```
const app = express();

app.set("json replacer", (k, v) => {
  return formatJSONNull(k, v);
});

var formatJSONNull = function (k, v) {
  if (v === null || v === undefined) {
    if (listValues.indexOf(k) >= 0) {
      return [];
    } else if (integerValues.indexOf(k) >= 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (boolValues.indexOf(k) >= 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
  return v;
};

const listValues = ['languages'];

const boolValues = ['language_count'];

const integerValues = ['language_count'];
```